# Virtual Hosts on XAMPP redirecting to /dashboard

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

Need help! :(

I am working on this for days, and still cant figure out the solution.

I am working with XAMPP 5.6.30 and Windows 10

I did the steps to configure new virtual hosts..

1. Uncommenting

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

2. Introducing my virtual hosts

   127.0.0.1       example.local-vhost
   127.0.0.1       supplier.local-vhost
   127.0.0.1       manage.local-vhost
3. And also adding this on my httpd-vhosts.conf

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/example
>   ServerName example.local-vhost
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/project-bo
>   ServerName supplier.local-vhost
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/project-bo
>   ServerName manage.local-vhost
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

4. Also I have restarted my Apache

But still no luck, it still redirect me to /dashboard

Please help.... what did i do wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to add or un-comment the `NameVirtualHost *:80` before the v-hosts

Answer (score -1):

add `/` at the end of the Document Root 
like this

```
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/project-bo/
```

Comment: I tried to do like that. When I did it my apache won't start. After I delete the / from the end of Document Root, apache successfully started to work.